# $(2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})(2+\sqrt{2})^n+(2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ is always integral

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that $(2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})(2+\sqrt{2})^n+(2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer for all $n \geq 0$.

By the Binomial Theorem:
\begin{equation}
2 \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{n-k} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{n-k} + 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (-\sqrt{2})^{n-k} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (-\sqrt{2})^{n-k} 
\end{equation}
If we distinguish the cases that $n$ is even or odd and $k$ is even or odd. We can reduce the problem to:

• $n$ even, $k$ even and $n$ odd, $k$ odd so $n-k$ is even: $ =4 \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{n-k}$

• $n$ odd, $k$ even and $n$ even, $k$ odd so $n-k$ is odd: $ =\sqrt{2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{n-k}$

Now we have to show that those above expressions both will produce integers for all $n \geq 0$. For $n-k$ even (resp. odd) I want to rewrite the above expressions. For
\begin{align} 4 \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{n-k}\end{align} 
I know $n-k=2l$ is even so $(\sqrt{2})^{n-k}$ is an integer but how can I use this to rewrite the expression? If $n=k+2l$ then:
\begin{align} 4 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{k+2l} {k+2l\choose k}2^k (\sqrt{2})^{2l}\end{align} How to deal with this?

Comment: What have you tried? "Binomial theorem" is a good start -- try to write down the powers according to that and group the terms to obtain cancellations of the $\sqrt{2}$'s.

Comment: Hint:  Use the symmetry $\sqrt2\mapsto -\sqrt2$.

Comment: From where you stopped, odd-odd combination gives $n-k$ even, so that's an integer. Other case similarly you get $n-k$ to be odd, so it's an integer too...

Comment: You are done.  Each term in the sum is an integer as you have shown the exponent of $\sqrt 2$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

Another way if you know linear recurrences. Show the first two terms are integer and show the characteristic equation leads to the recurrence
$$a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-2a_n$$

Comment: I explain this from scratch in my answer (no knowledge of recurrences assumed).

Answer (score 2):

let $a = 2 + \sqrt{2}/2$, $b = 2 - \sqrt{2}/2$, $x = 2 + \sqrt{2}$, $y = 2 - \sqrt{2}$.  For integers $n$, let  $$f(n) = ax^n + by^n.$$  Notice that we could get $f(n+1)$ as part of the terms obtained upon expansion of $(x+y)f(n)$; that is, consider $$\begin{align*} (x+y)f(n) &= (x+y)(ax^n + by^n) \\ &= ax^{n+1} + by^{n+1} + xy(ax^{n-1} + by^{n-1}) \\ &= f(n+1) + xy f(n-1). \end{align*}$$  But $x+y = 4$, and $xy = 2$, so $$f(n+1) = 4f(n) - 2f(n-1).$$  It immediately follows by induction that if $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are integers, then $f(n)$ is an integer for all integers $n \ge 0$.  So all that remains is to verify that $f(0) = a+b = 4$, and $f(1) = 5 + 3 \sqrt{2} + 5 - 3\sqrt{2} = 10$.  This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ b = 2+\sqrt{2},\,\ \bar b = 2-\sqrt{2}$

Then $b,\bar b\,$ roots of $\ (x\! -\!b)(x\!-\!\bar b) = x^2-4x+2 = f(x)$

$\ \Rightarrow\ b,\bar b\,$ roots of $\ x^{n+2}-4x^{n+1}+2x^n = x^n f(x)$

$\ \Rightarrow\ 0\, =\ \ a(b^{n+2}-4b^{n+1}+2b^n)$
$\qquad\quad\ \,+ \bar a(\bar b^{n+2}\!-4\bar b^{n+1}\!+2\bar b^n)$
$\qquad\quad =\ ab^{n+2}\!+\bar a\bar b^{n+2}\! - 4(ab^{n+1}\!+\bar a\bar b^{n+1})+ 2(ab^{n}\!+\bar a\bar b^{n})$
$\qquad\ \ \ =\ \  f_{n+2} - 4 f_{n+1} + 2 f_n,\ $ defining $\ \ f_n = ab^{n}\!+\bar a\bar b^{n}$

By induction $\,\forall n\!:\ f_n\in \Bbb Z\iff f_0,f_1\in \Bbb Z,\ $ true for your $\, a = 2 + \sqrt{2}/2\, $ since

$\qquad\qquad f_0 = a+\bar a = 4 $

$\qquad\qquad f_1 = ab+\bar a\bar b   = 10$

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange the given expression to obtain

$$ 2 \big[ (2+\sqrt{2})^n + (2-\sqrt{2})^n \big] + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big[ (2+\sqrt{2})^n - (2-\sqrt{2})^n \big] $$

Using binomial theorem, it is easy to see that the terms with odd power of $\sqrt{2}$ will cancel out inside the first square brackets.

In case of second square brackets, terms with even power of $\sqrt{2}$ will cancel out, leaving terms with odd power of $\sqrt{2}$. These odd powers will convert to even powers upon division by $\sqrt{2}$.

Since both terms are integers, their sum is also integer.